# move uiview in circular path

Tags: iphone, uiview, scroll, move

I want to move uiview in circular path clockwise and anticlockwise. Its like I have many images in a view which user can move in clockwise and anticlockwise direction along circular path. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You have to build an animation based upon, say, index of your image in array. So, 360 degrees divided by index of image will give you the angle. `cos(angle) = x`, `sin(angle) = y`. There you have it - the coordinates for each image. Now just place them and animate them.